# Getting the DATABASE Upon onCreateView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I have a fragment that display a recyclerview widget

when the list is empty, i want to display an imagebutton in the middle to tell the user to add content.

I link the view in onCreateView this way

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

            val view : View
            val repository = CrimeRepository.get()
            val crimes : LiveData<List<Crime>> = repository.getCrimes()


            if (crimes.value?.isEmpty() == true){

            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false)
              crimeRecyclerView =
                view?.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view) as RecyclerView
            crimeRecyclerView?.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(context)
        } else{
               view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_layout, container, false)
                imageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton) as ImageButton

                imageButton.setOnClickListener{
                    val crime = Crime()
                    crimeListViewModel.addCrime(crime)
                    callbacks?.onCrimeSelected(crime.id)
                }
        }

        return view
    }
```

my problem is getting the size of the crimes list... i only can get .value and that is never null even if it is empty...

usually i get it inside onViewCreated this way

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        crimeListViewModel.crimeListLiveData.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer { crimes ->
                crimes?.let {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got Crimes ${crimes.size}")
                    updateUI(crimes)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

I tried to do the same inside onCreateView, that never worked... maybe i can't find the right way to make the code...

when i get the data i can check if the size is zero or not...

any solution?

Comment: `and that is never null even if it is empty...` Why do you want it to be null? If the list is empty then its empty i would say.

Comment: it doesn't give me the option or allow me to use the function empty... it only give me .value... because im using the live data... also not able to get the list to use .size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i only can get .value and that is never null even if it is empty...

This is because the operation is asynchronous which means you have to wait before accessing the real value of crime list. You can do this by using observe which you already use but not in the right way.

Here is a nice and clean way to achieve what you want.

1. Use the xml layout you have for both the recyclerView and the imageButton. (Make sure to use FrameLayout as root layout)
2. Use android:visibillity=gone to imageButton by default
3. Inflate the layout as you already do in onCreateView but remove the inflation of imageButton
4. Observe live data in `OnViewCreated`
5. As soon as you get some data then act on it. You can have something like

```kotlin
crimeListViewModel.crimeListLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { crimes ->
                if(crimes.isNullOrEmpty() {
                   // show imageButton
                   // add click listener to imageButton
                } else {
                  // hide imageButton
                  // populate the recyclerView adapter with Items
                }            }
        )
```

Comment: this way gets the data but i thought i would do it by changing the layout... after all i did a similar way as you suggest... i put it in a constrained layout and added an image button... then on the update recyclerview i put condition with similar logic... thank you

Comment: You have to think a little different than usual when observing some liveData but once you get into the mind set it will look easier but generally using some visibility modifier is the way I do these kind of operations